# Rename or remove [old-games]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The tag wiki for [old-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-games) clearly states it should be for compatibility issues with no-longer-supported games, and I think that's a useful tag to have; unfortunately the tag name itself is not very informative, and a lot of [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) questions and even other questions about relatively old games get tagged with it.

I think the tag should either be altogether removed or at least be renamed to more explicitly represent its purpose, for example [old-games-compatibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-games-compatibility) or something like that.

**EDIT:** bump. The tag is still being abused. With 6 upvotes on Matthew's answer and no counter opinions, can we kill it now?

Comment: I *don't* think it's useful.  `compatibility` (existing) should be sufficient.  Is anyone really filtering for `old-games` so that they can say "Use DOSBox" or "Use an XP virtual machine" or whatever else all the time when it comes up?

Comment: @Matthew fair point, I think you should put it in a vote-able answer. At the very least, even if both `old-games` and `compatibility` are kept alive, we need to make a good distinction between them to justify it.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think [old-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-games) is useful.  [compatibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compatibility) should be sufficient.  Is anyone really filtering for `old-games` so that they can say "Use DOSBox" or "Use an XP virtual machine" or whatever else all the time when it comes up?  I would doubt it; and if they are, it probably wouldn't hurt anything to get them looking at a few other issues!

<sub>RE: Making a distinction if we keep it anyways — Definitely. `compatibility` is a substring of `old-games-compatibility`, meaning that searching for `[compatibility]` will show old-game-issues as well, but searching `[old-games-compatibility]` will not show non-old-game-issues. That's good, but doesn't quite solve the problem of people wanting to use both tags. And limiting `compatibility` to only non-old-game-issues would be weird/confusing.</sub>

Comment: If we're wanting it *only* for compatibility points, I'm far more in favor of just using [compatibility] alone than bothering specifically with old-games compatibility. Trying to maintain it for old games specifically has the reverse issue that [upcoming-games] had - instead of having to clear out the tag every so often, this time we'd have to troll [compatibility] every so often to *add* the corresponding old games tag. Also, old-games has otherwise proved about as useless as retro-games has.

Comment: @Grace Good points, I agree.

Comment: I think it's not only not useful, its current use is counterintuitive: people keep adding it to ITG questions because they think it means "questions about old games" when what they really want is something like `80s` or `old-platforms` or `something-you've-never-heard-of`.

Answer (score 5):

Aha!

See our new tag completion, which, crucially, *shows the relevant tag wiki excerpt at the time of tag selection!*

[image: new tag completion support]

So, **make sure those tag wiki excerpts explain *what the tag is for***, and hopefully this can help guide new users toward seleting the correct tag.

(additional guidance on [editing tag wikis and excerpts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) is available on the blog, too.)

Comment: I still think this specific tag is problematic, but in general I *really* like the tagging autocompletion change, and I definitely agree it can help with these sort of problems!