# Burnination request: classic-games

Tags: discussion, tags

Given that the only answer to the classic-games dilemma that got a positive score was essentially [no, we don't need it](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/do-we-need-a-classic-games-tag/2718#2718), I hereby second FallenAngelEyes' request:

> I think [this tag needs]* to die in a fire. The subjectivity issues as well as the potential necessity to reclassify games as time passes makes them pretty useless.

All in favor of burninating classic-games?

*Note that her actual quote is "both of these tags need to die in a fire." The other tag is [old-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-games), and there is an [open request](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/8366) to kill that tag.

Comment: `classic-games` is easy to remove with only 10 questions tagged.  I proposed it as [a synonym of `old-games`](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/old-games/synonyms) as well since, if nothing else is done, that will at least simplify things.

Answer (score 2):

As I already stated in [your other question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/do-we-need-a-classic-games-tag), I fully support burning this tag with fire.

UPDATE: Due to the previous meta, and chat conversations, I've already started deleting the tags. I'm splitting up the deletion to prevent clogging up the front page.

Comment: This is true. I hadn't actually requested it, though - I was just looking for discussion - so you didn't have a quote that I could pull. Support for arson is here, we're just watching for a mod with a match.